# How Do I Group Chart Data Points and Add a Series for the SUM of the grouping at each datapoint?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, charts

I am trying to group data in the graph below by datapoints of multiple series which are at 15 minute intervals.

As shown there are two series, and my program has the potential of adding infinite series of different names. How do I group the y-values of different series at the same points to add to the total cost series? I have already tried this:

```
chartDailyCost.DataManipulator.Group(
"SUM", 15, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalType.Minutes, "*");
```

Where "*" apparently groups multiple input series
Here is also the loop I am using to add the line graph to the chart:

```
chartDailyCost.Series.Add(textBoxApplianceName.Text);
chartDailyCost.Legends.Add(textBoxApplianceName.Text); 
chartDailyCost.Series[textBoxApplianceName.Text].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.
    DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;

while (starttime <= endtime)
{
   if ((starttime <= (Convert.ToDateTime("06:00"))) 
   && (starttime > (Convert.ToDateTime("00:00"))))
   {
     TotalCostLowPeak = TotalCost * (8.0 / 12.2);
     chartDailyCost.Series[textBoxApplianceName.Text].
                    Points.AddXY( starttime, TotalCostLowPeak);
   }
   if ((starttime <= (Convert.ToDateTime("10:00"))) 
   && (starttime > (Convert.ToDateTime("06:00"))))
   {
     TotalCostHighPeak = TotalCost * (16.1 / 12.2);
     chartDailyCost.Series[textBoxApplianceName.Text]
                   .Points.AddXY(starttime, TotalCostHighPeak);
   }
   if ((starttime <= (Convert.ToDateTime("16:00"))) 
   && (starttime > (Convert.ToDateTime("10:00"))))
   {
     chartDailyCost.Series[textBoxApplianceName.Text]
                   .Points.AddXY(starttime, TotalCost);
   }
  if ((starttime <= (Convert.ToDateTime("20:00"))) 
  && (starttime > (Convert.ToDateTime("16:00"))))
 {
   TotalCostHighPeak = TotalCost * (16.1 / 12.2);
   chartDailyCost.Series[textBoxApplianceName.Text]
                 .Points.AddXY(starttime, TotalCostHighPeak);
 }
 if ((starttime <= (Convert.ToDateTime("23:45"))) 
 && (starttime > (Convert.ToDateTime("20:00"))))
 {
     TotalCostLowPeak = TotalCost * (8.0 / 12.2);
     chartDailyCost.Series[textBoxApplianceName.Text]
                   .Points.AddXY(starttime, TotalCostLowPeak);
 }

 starttime = starttime.AddMinutes(15);
}
sumSeries(chartDailyCost);
```

Here I have tried the method TaW has recommended, but I am getting the error:

http://postimg.org/image/7pco8vrst/

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
private void sumSeries(Chart chartDailyCost)
    {
        chartDailyCost.Series.Remove(chartDailyCost.Series["Total Cost"]);

        List<Series> dataSeries = chartDailyCost.Series.ToList();
//this line shows an error when multiple series are added
        Series sumSeries = chartDailyCost.Series.Add("Total Cost");
        chartDailyCost.Series["Total Cost"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
        //I have initialised many of the chart formats in the form_load method

        for (int i = 1; i < dataSeries[0].Points.Count; i++)
        {
            double sum = 0d;

            //for every series in the chart collection sum the yvalues at the specified 
            foreach (Series s in dataSeries)
            {
                sum += s.Points[i].YValues[0];
            }
            DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
            //Add a new yvalue to the datapoint for the summed series's
            dp.XValue = dataSeries[0].Points[i].XValue;
            dp.YValues[0] = sum;
            sumSeries.Points.Add(dp);
        }
        //Add all of the data points to the "Total Cost" Series
        //chartDailyCost.Series.Add(sumSeries);//Found in above coding
    }
```

Comment: _I have already tried this:_ And what was the result? Can you post a link to an example of the desired output?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have a 10 reputation to do this, basically I want every series to sum at each data point e.g. at 01:15 group(sum (series 1, series 2 etc...) and then be able to plot that summed y-value to a new series at 01:15

Comment: At the moment when I have that line of code in, the "total" series does not display any data points, and when you add a series output, it says that there's not enough outputs

Comment: That's why I asked you to post a link; there are many free image hosting services.. So do I get this right: You want to have a Series  for the sums of the Values of all other Series at each point? Sounds straight forward: write a loop over all points and in it a loop over all other series, sum the values and add the new points to the sums series.. How dynamic are the data? Will change a lot?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/lg74rxdn7/

Comment: The data is dynamic, in that there are no series initially, and you add them one by one

Comment: Maybe I have gotten you wrong; are the groups you want to see in your image?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/tj4e0dakh/ On another tab I have a combobox where people can select their device, and times etc..., and the graph at the moment add a new line for each device. In the legend on the top right their is a total cost  field which should be summing the data. The groups are not in the graph at the moment.

Comment: Potentially could I have a different series for the sum of each data point if this is easier "00:15", "00:30", "00:45" etc...?

Comment: Are those 15 minute intervals the normal x-values? In that case, would the code in the answer do the job?

Comment: Yes but I can't figure out how to use the private void, I've tried initialising the chart and list but it doesn't work:       private void sumSeries(Chart chartDailyCost, List<>)

Answer (score 1):

The code example assumes that you want to sum all values of all series into the points of a new series. Also that all series have the same number of points and the same `XValues`.

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
...
...
void sumSeries(Chart chart)
{
    List<Series> dataSeries = chart.Series.ToList();
    Series sumSeries = chart.Series.Add("Total");
    // insert charttype and styles here!
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSeries[0].Points.Count; i++)
    {
        double sum = 0d;

        foreach (Series s in dataSeries)
        {
            sum += s.Points[i].YValues[0];
        }
        DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
        dp.XValue = dataSeries[0].Points[i].XValue;
        dp.YValues[0] = sum;
        sumSeries.Add(dp);
    }
}
```

This add a new `Series sumSeries`. Be sure to **remove** it before you call the function a second time to reflect updated data..

Comment: For the statement of the arguements in the private void I have tried using these but I'm having no luck:        private void sumSeries(Chart chartDailyCost, List<>)

Comment: You would simply call `sumSeries(chartDailyCost);`, the list is created inside.. you can always modify it, if you want the summation to be in the 1st series..

Comment: Hey sorry for asking another question, and I really appreciate your help, but can you refer to the editted code in my original post for the error code I am getting with the method?

Comment: Yup, you are missing a using directive: `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;` Only a few charts methods&members are available without it but it is a nice space save to not haig to qualify the long mnamespace..

Comment: Hey that was great the method works now and I am getting the total cost field to show up, Cheers!!! However, as shown in http://postimg.org/image/7pco8vrst/ The chart is now plotting as intended, but I am also getting an error for trying to add multiple series as shown in the comments I have made, there needs to be a method of   clearing the series, to which I have tried a Dispose() which didn't quite work. I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: To delete all points in a series you write Series.Points.Clear(); To delete a Series s1 you  write: chart.Series.Remove(s1); to deletes all Series in a Chart you write chart.Series.Clear();

Comment: Hey that works at allowing the multiple series to add to the chart, but has stopped the total cost chart plotting any data points. Do you think it's because the for statement is adding 1 values, and maybe it needs to be 15 minute datetime intervals? Or is it another reason, thanks again

Comment: Hard to tell for me. What are the times between the data points? (You do call the sumSeries function and the Total Cost series is shown in the legend?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/g56sa7vfn/ Yer the time interval is 15 minutes from the while loop in the original code, but on the chart I'm only showing the hours grid, the total cost is showing in the legend each time, and is changing color, showing that it is being removed and redrawn

Comment: Hm, sounds like a good time to use the debugger to check the values of the datapoints (if any) that are create in sumSeries! (And a good time to go to bed for me..)

Comment: Haha have a good sleep! This is where I'm leaving it tonight http://postimg.org/image/lye4q7v5t/

Comment: It always adds the points correctly up to 6am, and then after theat it doesn't add correctly, and it always stops at 09:30 for some reason.     What I am thinking is that there needs to be a loop for searching the dp.xvalue=dataseries[0].points[i].xvalue; where i is to be changed by a 15 minute interval, but it requires an int value which I haven't been able to do tonight.

Comment: Hm, just noticed that my code added the Total Series twice, i guess you must have corrected that yourself. Not sure about your graph: Not only do the number of columns look wrong, their sizes don't match the data either! Do change the charttype to point or something smaller and do use the debugger to peek into the series and their points. I'll be away for the day..

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/5qo1nemzb/ Hey this is what I get when I changed it to datapoints, basically it can be seen to plot only a couple of points, at the start and end of the range.

Comment: Apologies, but how could I use the debugger to look at a series I created in code? And have a good day!

Comment: _how could I use the debugger to look at a series_ This is by far the most importatn thing to do now for you!! The debugger is extremly important to find the kind of mistakes you have at the moment.. Step one: Set a breakpoint at a piece of code, maybe in the setSum function! (To do so you click at the leftmost part of a line and see how a fat red circle come up) 2) when you are there you can either step further (F10 & F11) or look into all varibales of your program. To do so there are servel choices..

Comment: .. - You can set the cursor over a varible name in the current piece of code or - you can look at the local pane in the bottom left - or you can press Ctrl-D-Q to create a quick watch. drill into the variable by clicking the small triangles, as usual..

Comment: Besides playing with the debugger: Do change the charttype of all series to Point for testing! I'm curious if those missing sumPoints are not actully coming from missing data points..?